# Why give an Error?

Tags: java, multithreading

I just want to find out why this piece of code throws an Error. The Error is :

> "Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.Error"

```
class Salmon extends Thread
{
    public static long id;
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<4; i++){
            if(i==2&& id ==Thread.currentThread().getId()){
            //if(i==2){
                new Thread(new Salmon()).start();
                throw new Error();
             }
             System.out.println(i + " ");
          }
     }
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         Thread t1 = new Salmon();
          id = t1.getId();
          t1.start();
      }
}
```

Comment: what the error you are getting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you tell it to.

```
 if(i==2){
          new Thread(new Salmon()).start();
          throw new Error(); // <----
```

Comment: why then does it still throw the same error if the if condition is now
if(i==2&& id ==Thread.currentThread().getId())?
the Id's, as I checked were different and yet it still executes the conditions if the case was true. why?

Comment: You are telling it throw an error if i is equal to 2 and the id of the current thread is equal to the id of the current thread. Which will happen when i equals 2. Just take out the line `throw new Error()` if you do not want it to throw an error.

Comment: but why does it still throw the error even when i equals 2 but the Thread.currentId() is not 2?

Answer (score 3):

I think your question might be better specified "why does execution continue beyond `new Thread(new Salmon()).start();`?  You're starting a new thread.  When you call `start()`, execution of the `run()` method in the new thread continues *in parallel* with the continued execution after the immediately-returning `start()` method.

Answer (score 1):

`id == Thread.currentThread().getId()` is always true for the first thread (t1) that you start from your main thread.

As soon as `i` reaches 2 in that thread, `if(i == 2 && id == Thread.currentThread().getId())` will be true as well and the following code will be executed:

```
new Thread(new Salmon()).start();
throw new Error();
```

As already pointed out, `new Thread(new Salmon()).start();` returns immediately (the newly created thread runs in parallel with t1) and t1 continues to the next line, which throws an exception.